# Restrict user to use only network provided time

Tags: flutter, datetime

I made an attendance app in Flutter in which I want to restrict employees to use only network provided time so that employees won't be able to temper the date and time.

Is there any option or solution to implement this in android and iOS as well?

Comment: Isn't it better if you use your server timestamp?

Comment: but my app works offline

Comment: Try `DateTime.now()`

Comment: DateTime.now() gets date from mobile if an employee manually changes the time then DateTime shows that manually changed time

Answer (score 1):

Using this package [datetime_settings](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_setting) we will get the settings of Automatic date & time of mobile so when automatic date & time is on mobile will give us an accurate network time otherwise we will show an error to turn on the automatic date & time in settings. That's how I used to restrict users to use only network-provided time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you what worked for me. Hope this can help you. I don't know if it's the most optimized way to do it, but it worked very well for me:

You need to create an internal clock for your app, and from this, use it instead of the DateTime.now() function. For this, you must take the server time when opening the app, and keep it updated with a timer that runs every 1 second.
Please note that the app goes to sleep (or closes) when the device is locked or the app is minimized for a certain amount of time (this depends on the operating system and battery saver settings), thereby stopping the internal clock, and consequently, it is delayed when the app is activated again. In my case, I got around this problem by using a foreground service that I designated to perform this task (I used [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task)). Another advantage of using a foreground service, is that the user can close the app and the clock keeps running (and in my case, I also perform other simple tasks periodically).

If the user does not manipulate the system time, the difference should never reach 1 second.

Optionally, you could check when retrieving the server time, the difference with the device time, and if it is greater than a certain gap that you determine, warn the user, so that he can correct it if he prefers, so that he does not see a discrepancy with the time recorded and displayed by the application.

Regards.